# Sinon Spies -- Testing a recursive (and possibly const) function expression

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

I am using Mocha with Sinon and attempting to test a recursive call (fibonacci). My code is:

```
'use strict';

let sinon = require('sinon'),
    chai = require('chai'),
    expect = chai.expect;

chai.use(require('sinon-chai'));

let fib = function (n) {
    if (n === 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (n === 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1);
    }
};

describe('fib', function() {
        it('should repeat calculations', function() {
            let originalFib = fib;
            fib = sinon.spy(fib)

            expect(fib(6)).to.equal(8);
            expect(fib).to.have.callCount(25);

            fib = originalFib;
        });
});
```

This code works as-is, however, if I replace the line:

```
let fib = function (n) {
```

with:

```
const fib = function (n) {
```

I get the following error:

*TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.*

This is as expected, but it raises the question, how would I test a recursive function that was declared const using Sinon?

**Edited** Jasmine has something called .callThrough() which seems to allow testing of recursive function.

It seems to me there is no way to replicate this behavior with Sinon? I have  looked at the following bug reports / feature requests:

https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/668

https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/989

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `sinon.spy` directly on a function creates a wrapper around the original function that tracks calls and returned values but does not modify it, so you do not need to remember it and restore it.

With that information, the obvious answer would be to simply name your spy something else:

```
describe('fib', function() {
  it('should repeat calculations', function() {
    const spy = sinon.spy(fib);

    expect(spy(6)).to.equal(8);
    expect(spy).to.have.callCount(25);
  });
});
```

This approach works fine for non-recursive functions, but as you might notice, while the first assertion passes, the second fails with only 1 call having been made to spy.

The problem is that there is one more issue at play here.  The function fib calls itself directly and those direct recursive calls are not tracked by wrapping the function with `sinon.spy`.

More details on this issue as well as the corresponding solution is presented in [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51699585/10149510).

Comment: Thank you for your response! Am I to understand that the only way to test a recursive function is to re-write it, such that it calls the wrapper object? This seems like an unacceptable practice to me, as my code could change from what I've re-written in the test. I am attempting to memo-ize fib, but, I want to memo-ize it by applying a function wrapper.  Jasmine has something called  .callThrough() that Sinon does not have?

Comment: @DanielLynch this is a question that keeps getting asked in different ways (different details such as which testing framework, etc.) so I created a new question/answer that explains the issue in detail and presents the corresponding solution.  I edited my answer above to link to that answer.  Let me know if it covers what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue when you changed the code into `const fib = function(n)` is because you have this subsequent code `fib = sinon.spy(fib)`. We can't redeclare assignment for any variable with `const`.

For this kind of test, based on my experience, I feel that using `spy` is not necessary unless you have other function to call inside `fib`. We can just execute and check the value for all possible cases.

```
'use strict';

const sinon = require('sinon'),
      chai = require('chai'),
      expect = chai.expect;

chai.use(require('sinon-chai'));

const fib = function (n) {
  if (n === 0) {
    return 0;
  } else if (n === 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1);
  }
};

describe('fib', function () {
  it('should repeat calculations', function () {
    expect(fib(0)).to.equal(0); // add more cases
    expect(fib(1)).to.equal(1);
    expect(fib(6)).to.equal(8);
  });
});
```

Hope it helps.